# What does mean "He pitched the song up"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Yesterday, I watched a video clip of my favourite band on YouTube. The video was not the official one, it was assembled by an ordinary person who also changed the singer's voice just a little bit (his voice got higher).

I made a comment about that video: "One of the best songs of this band!".

Someone else made a comment in reply to mine: "Did you notice that he pitched the song up?"

What did that reply mean?

Comment: Did you look up **[pitch up](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pitch_up)**?

Comment: @CowperKettle I think "up" in that sentence is because he was referring to the video that stays above the comments.

Comment: CowperKettle's link has two definitions, and the second one is "To raise the pitch of (a sound)," which is certainly what is being talked about here (the OP said, "his voice got higher").  As someone with some small musical experience, I wouldn't say that I've heard "pitch up" very often, but I would immediately guess that it means "[transpose](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transpose) to a higher key."  As in, "I could sing this in D, but I'd be more comfortable if we could pitch it up to F or even F#."

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thank you! Now I got it! "Pitch up" in this context means "to high a note".

Comment: **pitch up** is an oddball phrasal verb that many native speakers (of AmE)  would not know the meaning of.

Comment: @Renato **high** is not a verb but an adjective.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I thought I could say "to high"... But, I know "to up" can be said.

Comment: Yes, **He upped the pitch** is the usual way of expressing this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds quite reasonable English to me. A song has a pitch, say D-major. You could make the pitch a bit higher, like E-major, which makes it easier to handle low notes.

He changed the pitch of the song to a higher pitch. He changed the pitch of the song up. He pitched up the song.

(It may be a recent addition to the language, but English is flexible).

Answer (score 0):

> He altered the pitch to be higher.

It is improper internet grammar.

Edit: I was wrong. *To pitch up* is actually valid according to Cowper Kettle's comment.

Comment: CowperKettle has an *impressive* command of the language, but he's not a native speaker. Trust your instincts.  To **pitch up** is a neologism, as a phrasal verb. As a noun meaning "a tangle, an altercation" (**a pitch-up**) it is over 100 years old, though that noun is restricted to regional dialect use.

Comment: I am a native speaker.  To "pitch up" makes perfect sense in context to me.  Even if it is a new usage, it's a perfectly valid construction.